# Oracle Cloud ATP database unavailable for ORDS

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-ords

It happens to me several times each month, that my Oracle Cloud ATP database service becomes unavailable for the ORDS. Anyone having a similar experience? What can be done in such a situation as Oracle does not have any direct support options?

[image: ORDS 404 error]

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: In general, the database went to "Unavailable" state. No warning, no visible issue. From ORDS status perspective, it was HTTP 404 during this period. After several hours, the database returned to "Available" again.

Comment: Did you check the database state on OCI Console, as well? I mean was the database really unavailable in general, or just ORDS didn't work?